# Advent of Code 2019, Day 2 in Haskell

Tags: haskell

This is my solution for [Day 2 of Advent of Code 2019](https://adventofcode.com/2019/day/2).

It's the `eval` function I want to get reviewed. Is this acceptable Haskell code? Is it even close to being idiomatic? Also, is it OK to leverage laziness this way?

```hs
module Day2 where

import Data.Vector (Vector, fromList, head, (!), (//))
import Data.List.Split (splitOn)

type Intcode = Vector Int

data Op = Add | Mult | Noop

intToOp :: Int -> Op
intToOp 1 = Add
intToOp 2 = Mult
intToOp 99 = Noop
intToOp x = error $ "invalid opCode, should not happen" ++ show x

eval :: Intcode -> Intcode
eval intcode = go intcode 0
  where
    go intcode currentIndex =
      let
        op = intToOp $ intcode ! currentIndex
        v1Pos = intcode ! (currentIndex + 1)
        v2Pos = intcode ! (currentIndex + 2)
        savePos = intcode ! (currentIndex + 3)
        nextIndex = currentIndex + 4
        v1 = intcode ! v1Pos
        v2 = intcode ! v2Pos
      in
        case op of
          Add -> go (intcode // [(savePos, (v1 + v2))]) nextIndex
          Mult -> go (intcode // [(savePos, (v1 * v2))]) nextIndex
          Noop -> intcode

part1 :: IO ()
part1 = do
  input <- readFile "../input/day2.txt"
  let intcode = fromList (read <$> splitOn "," input)
  let result = eval $ intcode // [(1, 12), (2, 2)]
  putStrLn $ show $ result ! 0

part2 :: IO ()
part2 = do
  input <- readFile "../input/day2.txt"
  let memory = fromList (read <$> splitOn "," input)
  let inputs = [(i, j) | i <- [0..99], j <- [0..99]]
  let results = fmap (\(noun, verb) -> (eval $ memory // [(1, noun), (2, verb)], noun, verb)) inputs
  let (result, noun, verb) = Prelude.head $ filter (\(res, _, _) -> (res ! 0) == 19690720) results
  putStrLn $ show $ 100 * noun + verb
```

Comment: Links can rot. [Please include a description of the challenge here in your question.](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1993)

Answer (score 2):

`slice` combines some lookups. The index arithmetic can be frontloaded.

```
eval :: Intcode -> Intcode
eval = go [0,4..] where
  go (index:es) intcode =
    let
      [opcode, v1Pos, v2Pos, savePos] = toList $ slice index 4 intcode
      v1 = intcode ! v1Pos
      v2 = intcode ! v2Pos
    in
      case intToOp opcode of
        Add  -> go es $ intcode // [(savePos, v1 + v2)]
        Mult -> go es $ intcode // [(savePos, v1 * v2)]
        Noop -> intcode
```

`//` takes linear time on immutable vectors. `Noop` should be `Halt`. This displays the unreliability of adding data types for their suggestive names. Therefore, inline `intToOp`.

```
eval :: Intcode -> Intcode
eval = modify $ \intcode ->
  void $ runMaybeT $ for_ [0,4..] $ \index -> do
    [opcode, v1Pos, v2Pos, savePos] <- traverse (read intcode) [index..index+3]
    v1 <- read intcode v1Pos
    v2 <- read intcode v2Pos
    case opcode of
      1 -> lift $ write intcode savePos $ v1 + v2
      2 -> lift $ write intcode savePos $ v1 * v2
      99 -> empty
      _ -> error $ "invalid opCode, should not happen" ++ show opcode
```

Of course, all of this imperativeness doesn't feel Haskell. However, interpreting an imperative language is pretty much the one time you need not feel bad about that.